# Problem with catching Preference Item click event

Tags: android, preferences, android-preferences, sharedpreferences

I'm building an android application and I have a pretty dumb question -

I've created a preference screen and put in it a list and a checkBox. Now I handled those just fine, using the 'key' attribute that is saved automatically.

My problem comes when I try using a simple Preference Item(they type that you just press it).
What is saved in `SharedPreference` when it's clicked? If nothing, how can I catch the click event?

I can't find an answer anywhere.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tofira,

You need to use `setOnPreferenceClickListener()` for that particular item.  See example:

```
Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("myPref");
myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    //handle action on click here
    }
});
```